# How to get the text value of a control through its parent window

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I have the following `wxDialog` parent window:

[image]

I have created that parent window by the following code:

```
settingsFrm settingsWindow(this, "Settings");
settingsWindow.ShowModal();
```

I have tried to use `FindWindowByName` to get the value of the first text ctrl as follow:

```
wxLogMessage(dynamic_cast<wxTextCtrl*>(settingsWindow->FindWindowByName("keywords_txt"))->GetValue());
```

But unfortunately, it doesn't work and gives me a runtime error.
I don't know if that method suitable to do what I want.

**How to get the value/other of a control through its parent window?**

Comment: can you show the code for the settingsFrm constructor? I hope you do have a class member pointer there which you can reference.

Comment: @Igor: The constructor doesn't have anything important, anyway open this [link](https://onlinegdb.com/HyerpoPpM).

Comment: what is keywordTxt and where it is being initialized? But this is not the issue. The issue is that you are trying to write a program using an unfamiliar language. Get a class on C++ (the language is very non-trivial) or learn python and write something using wxPython/Phoenix (will be much easier and faster). Because the problem you are facing is C++ one.

Comment: @Igor: `keywordTxt ` is a name of `wxTextCtrl` which is the first text box in the previous picture.

Answer (score 0):

From your comments, it seems like you expect the function to find the control from the name of the variable in your code which is not how it works and would be pretty much impossible.

`FindWindowByName()` uses the *window* name (and, as a fallback, label, but this is irrelevant here because text controls don't have labels anyhow), so for it to work you need to set the window name when creating the control, using the corresponding parameter of its ctor. This is very rarely useful in C++ code, however, as it's simpler to just store a pointer to the control in some variable and use this instead.

`FindWindowByName()` can often be useful when creating controls from XRC, however. If you do this, then you should specify names for your controls in XRC and pass the same name to this function.

Answer (score 0):

How did you create the TextCtrl instance? You should have something like `wxTextCtrl m_textCtrl1 = new wxTextCtrl(/// arguments);` Accessing the value should be very easy, as `wxString text = m_textCtrl1->GetValue();` You definitely don't need `FindWindowByName` just for what you are trying to do here.